# Determine if generated date falls on a holiday (PHP)?

Tags: php, date, bank

Does anyone know of an existing library or even a useful function that would allow a php script to check if a generated date clashes with a holiday, whether it be US, UK, AUS, or SAF holidays?

If there is no library are there any useful sources online which I could harness to develop my own?

Comment: try to read this links: http://www.developpez.net/forums/d493195/php/scripts/calendrier/recuperer-dates-vacances-scolaires-cest-possible/ there are many xml files to help you

Comment: try out strtotime: `if(time() == strtotime('third monday of january')) { ... }`

Comment: This guy’s implementation of a US holiday check was nice: http://www.damia.no/calculating-u-s-federal-holidays-with-php/

Answer (score 4):

I just google about this because this is interesting subject and i havn't tried it but it seems possible using pear package.

Here is link : http://pear.php.net/package/Date_Holidays

Here is example: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.datetime.date-holidays.example.php

Hope this helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

I found this useful package this morning:

http://maccrafters.com/home/current-offerings/programming/php-holiday-class/

It is pretty easy to adapt it and make it more powerful, but it is very user friendly and works well so far. It also has a nice feature for getting the next business day from a particular date.

Answer (score 0):

Some option can be: Michalmanko/Holiday is a small library to check if a specified date is a holiday in a specific country.
https://github.com/michalmanko/php-library-holiday